# find intersection on pie chart on power bi

Tags: powerbi

| Customer | Score | Grade | Q1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AA | 80 | Gold | 1 |
| BB | 75 | Silver | 1 |
| CC | 80 | Gold | 1 |
| BB | 75 | Silver | 2 |
| CC | 75 | Silver | 2 |
| DD | 80 | Gold | 2 |
| CC | 65 | Bronze | 3 |
| DD | 75 | Silver | 3 |
| EE | 100 | Platinum | 3 |

I have a table as above. My aim is to compare in 2 pie charts that only customers belong to compare months. (Intersections)

İ.e If I compare q1 and q2 (I have added q2 as duplicate of Q1)

bb and cc need to be compared because aa is not in q2 and dd is not in q1. and grade needs to be  q1 1 silver 1 gold, q2 2 silver

if comparing q1 and q3 only cc needs to be compared in pie chart.

I have 2 slicers for quarters on my page and can check changes in the table but not in the pie chart.
[image: Example table view and pi chart need to be converted]

so as above table has a measure to filter customers without scores.